# Converting this NFA to Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, finite-automata, nondeterminism, simulation

I'm asked to choose a DFA and convert it to NFA and then convert it to Turing machine... I have done the first two parts as follows:

## DFA:

[image: DFA]

## --> NFA:

[image: NFA]

## --> Turing machine:

## ???

I haven't found any explanation/tutorial on how to do this. So, a final solution containing a state diagram with an explanation on what steps were followed would be great.

Comment: Every DFA is already an NFA.

Answer (score 5):

A DFA is simply a Turing machine that moves the head to the right on every transition until it reaches the first blank tape cell.

<sub>Thanks to [Ryan](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/20256/ryan) for a comment that clarified this answer.</sub>

Comment: It is obvious, but the OP should note that this should say "to the right on every transition *if the cell is non-blank*".

Comment: So it is exactly the same state diagram? I need a complete answer quickly please.

Comment: We're not a do-my-homework service!

Comment: @iMe I've already given you practically the whole answer. If you understand what a DFA is and what a Turing machine is, you should be able to finish it. If not, ask your course instructor for help. I can't write it down as a Turing machine because I don't know what notation you use and because I think I've already done enough of your homework for you.

Comment: the question asks about a NFA though